# Why won't these DIVs align correctly?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I've got 3 DIVs which are within a "containing" DIV. The container is 960px wide and  the 3 DIVs have a width of 45%, 10%, and 45%. And they're all "floated left". Simple enough right?

Well for some reason the 3 DIVs won't align correctly, i.e. next to each other. The middle DIV is always above the DIV on the right. What am I doing wrong? Here's a fiddle to illustrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/m2Zzw/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="mTopContainer"> 
    <div class="mTopInner clearfix">
        <div class="leftBlock floatLeft">
            <p>[Customer], we have found 126 results for you, which are based on a mortgage of £50,000 over a period of 17 years.</p>
            <p>The mortgage will be secured against a property with a value of £100,000, meaning that you will be borrowing 50% of the property's purchase price.</p>
            <p>We used your answers to find the lenders more likely to accept you and the rates they are likely to offer you – the rates and lenders may therefore differ from those featured on our homepage. The actual rates offered to you may differ from that shown.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="middleBlock floatLeft">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="rightBlock floatLeft">
            <h6>Your next step</h6>
            <p>Get advice from one of our expert mortgage partners, Sensible Financial Solutions – FTB Prime and take the hassle out of finding the right mortgage for your needs.</p>

            <p>Any advice provided is not given either by or on behalf of [company].</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mTopContainer { width:100%; height:250px;  border:1px solid #BDD7EF;  margin-top:15px;  } 
/*.mTopInner  { height:250px; background: url('/Images/Mortgages/restoplady.png') top right no-repeat;   }   */
.leftBlock { width:45%; }
.middleBlock { width:10%; border-right:1px solid #BDD7EF; margin:0 auto; }
.rightBlock { width:45%; }

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table;  }  
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }  
/* For IE 6/7 only */  
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.floatLeft { float:left; }
```

Comment: Your problem is the border. You have `45% + 10% + 45% + border` which is `100% + border` so the 3 elements don't fit in one _row_.

Comment: There's a `border` on the middle div element

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't realise that this added to the width :/ Will fix it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used to this

```
.middleBlock{ box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
```

because you are using **border** and used to **width**

than your width is `width + border` == > **Total width of your div**

`box-sizing` is `css3` **properties**

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Zzw/5/)**

Comment: Perfect thanks! Just had a read about this on Paul Irish's blog...just tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you use exact percent to match 100%, all CSS property that work with margin or padding will be important.
In your code, you add a `border-right` property with 1px size, then your DIV will be 10% + 1px so there isn't enought space for your right DIV and it goes under the middle one.

Solution : use middle div as a container and add the border-right in another DIV inside.

Answer (score 0):

With some margin you should fix it
Margin-left: ...%;
Margin-top:....%

If you try that, where the ... are you have to put a value.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want compatibility with old browsers, just remove the border on the middle div. Then you can hack it back in by using a pixel background image, position it to the right and set it to repeat on Y-axis.

Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks, trying to avoid hacks and we're supporting IE8 > so the accepted answer should be ok

Comment: I probably misused the term 'hack' here, but sure, if CSS3 works for you, go for it!

Comment: Haha I know what you mean. Shame we need to use hacks anyway. Bloody Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

Because 45% + 10% + 45% + 1px border > 100%

You should add

```
.middleBlock{
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

in your stlyesheet